# Content appears over a corner when using border-radius

Tags: html, css

When using CSS3 `border-radius` property to create rounded corners how would one keep the content (text, images, etc.) from appearing over the top of the corner?

Example: [image: Example]

Might be hard to tell with this but I hope you guys understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the content inside of the box, you could use `padding` property:

```css
.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: gold;

  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px;  /* or */
                 /* padding-left: 10px */

  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) is used to to calculate *width* and *height* of the element including *padding* and probable *border*.

Here is the **[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/azOQEYI/1/edit)**

Comment: At first when you simply suggested padding I was thinking "well that works, but it messes with the sizing," but with box-sizing this is absolutely perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work in other browser but in Chrome you can just add:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to the container and this will fix it.
Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6qUh8/) of the overflow in action.

Comment: I am aware of this technique however I was hoping to keep all content visible but like shift it to the right.

Comment: Why not just adding a padding to the container element then?