# Circle div with text inside borders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How you can see (http://jsfiddle.net/m3c_/VWQjj/) text go outside div border.

```
<div id="myDiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>

#myDiv {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background-color: #00b7ea;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

How can I fix it? Any jQuery Plugin?

I'm looking for a rounded text area, not squared! Text must follow a rounded border like this:

[image]

Comment: check this [link](http://www.csstextwrap.com/examples.php).

Comment: Yes, same problem but i search a different solution. A lot of additional markup is not a good idea...IMHO.

Comment: IMHO, I think that @Johnツ solution is actually the only possible way. There's actually not a valid and easy solution to align text in a non-regular shape, such as a circle. Only HTML elements aligned with CSS or a JS solution can give what you are looking for. Maybe a further solution could be found in using CANVAS, but you still have to follow the programming approach to align the text into the shape.

Comment: Following edit 2, this functionality is not possible using pure CSS. All HTML elements are rectangular.

Comment: Yep I don't looking for a pure HTML solution... but maybe, a jquery plugin...?Somethings like this: http://baconforme.com/

In fourth example, if you use this:

175 0
0 75
0 225
175 300

175 0
0 75
0 225
175 300

you can have A way... I hope not the only one.

Comment: take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169806/text-within-circle-div-div-size-adjusted-to-content/19169939#19169939)

Comment: @avrahamcool thx for help but it don't fix my problem, I don't want a ectangle inside the circle...

Answer (score 0):

Increase the padding value and center the text:

```
#myDiv {
    padding: 2em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: not fix my problem man, see edit please...

Comment: You are trying to create a circular element, which is not possible. All HTML elements are rectangular blocks. You could achieve your desired result using a stack of spans with set width but it would be messy.

Comment: I know but I looking for a jQuery Plugin that can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can need to do like this.

Wrap the text within another element.
Set line-height to div height on the parent element.

Reset the line height on child (text) element.

```
<div class="ff"><span>This works</span></div>

<div class="ff"><span>Even this is working</span></div>
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/rbCrQ/7/)

[Your fiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/VWQjj/7/)

Comment: thx, good hack but there is a lot of empty spaces on top and bottom... in my idea, text must fill all the div...

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with the padding

```
padding: 40px 40px 10px;
```

Comment: Thx but it don't fix my problem. Text don't follow circle border, I need a "bubble text area" not a "square text area"...

Answer (score 0):

you have to keep your design as it is . don't change it

```
<div id="myDiv">
       <div id="my_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur  
        adipisicing   
    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div> 
    </div>
 #myDiv {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 2px solid #000;
background-color: #00b7ea;
text-align:center;



 padding: 10px;
  }
  #my_text
{
position:relative;top:16px;
```

}

// now you can control your text alone

Comment: yes, alone but in a squared mode... see edit please.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this css attributes into your css class `#myDiv`

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18498206/829533

your updated code will show like in this http://jsfiddle.net/VWQjj/8/

now you will notice still the text is going out of your div box, this is because of the is larger then the limit of the box,

to fix that you need to

1. remove some text or increase the size of box,
2. use `overflow:hidden` that will at least remove those weird text outflow, http://jsfiddle.net/VWQjj/9/ 
   but option 1 is more recommend over the 2

Comment: box-sizing have not any effect and overflow cut my text. When increase box size or remove text I move the problem, don't fix it...

Comment: what browser you are using? did you check the demo link i showed you? http://jsfiddle.net/VWQjj/8/

Comment: well i have written clearly that `overflow:hidden` will cut the text and since you need to increase the box size and/or decrease the text and/or text size so show it in the box,

Comment: but this is only helpful if the `box-sizing` works for you.. `box-sizing` and increasing decreasing stuffs are not two different solutions.

Comment: google chrome for win 7, latest dev release. this is how you fiddle works... http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/8444/i4fh.jpg i've updated box size how you can see.

Answer (score 0):

give the div a border radius.

{
border-radius : 50%
}

Comment: ehm... what? I already do this...